# Is there anyway in Desire2Learn (D2L) to restrict the list of Roles in Release Conditions?

Tags: desire2learn

Due to other constraints in roles/permissions, we have several roles that serve system and administrative functions.  We also like our faculty to be able to customize their classrooms and in particular to use release conditions to help with that.  Is there anyway to restrict the list of roles that they can use in release conditions to a set of "academic" roles and not show the administrative roles?

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you cannot restrict the roles that show up in the release conditions dialog. I've verified that release condition code always retrieves all the roles for the Org.

Thanks,
Matt